# Angular 5 Highlight extra content on textarea | Type in a textarea, show it in a div | Scroll issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I want to create a textarea which shows hightlighted text after a length.
So my logic is to create a textarea on a div, user types on textarea and data renders on a div.

```
Here is my HTML:
    <div class="form-control" #dummytext ></div>
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="actual" class="form-control" (input)="onInput($event, dummytext)"
                        spellcheck="false"></textarea>
    <div class="characters">{{ actual.length}} of {{maxlength}}</div>


Here is my js :
this.maxlength = '10';
actual = '';
onInput = (e, dummytext) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        if (value.length > this.maxlength) {
            const extra = value.substr(this.maxlength);
            const a = value.substr(0, this.maxlength) + '<span style="color: red;">' + extra + '</span>';
            dummytext.innerHTML = a.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
        } else {
            dummytext.innerHTML = value.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
        }
        dummytext.scrollTop = e.target.scrollTop;
    }


And my CSS:
    .form-control {
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    textarea {
        position: absolute;
        width: 91.9%;
        top: 50px;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        background: transparent;
        color: inherit;
        text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
        resize: none;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        height: 71% !important;
    }
    .characters {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: $col-active-gray;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
```

Using CSS, I have changed color of cursor and transparent the actual color.

I have completed most of the things. Issue I am facing is, after my scroll appears of div and press up key, it actually takes me to textarea data(obviously because of focus).

Here is working plunker: 
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/4Bgo9dewg7BThivt?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1

Using contenteditable=true is also creating issue. Here is the reference I took. 
https://codepen.io/gtb104/pen/pztgH
It allows me to type but not left right arrow keys.

How can I resolve it ? 
Please Help!!
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngStyle on text area

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="actual" class="form-control" [ngStyle]="{'color': (actual.length > 10) ? 'red' : 'greeen' }" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I want to highlight only the extra content and not the all.